# Why in Linux, golang run Http service will automatically create multiple child processes？

Tags: linux, go, process

This is what I used to do the test code

```go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":9301",
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/line/getList", Response)
    s.ListenAndServe()
}

func Response(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)  {

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    w.WriteHeader(200)

    for i:= 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        w.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    }
}
```

Here is the situation when the code runs

[image: htop output showing a tree with nested apptest threads]

System is centos 6.5

This normal? If not normal, how to limit golang automatically create a large number of child processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `htop` program is displaying threads, not processes. What you are seeing is Go's natural creation of threads which are used to run goroutines and to run system calls without blocking in the kernel.

[You can control the number of threads created with the GOMAXPROCS environment variable.](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/29/a-whirlwind-tour-of-gos-runtime-environment-variables)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do they all have different PIDs?

Comment: @Kaedys: They don't. That confused me too so I copied the code and ran it myself. What looks like different PIDs is htop displaying the TIDs instead.

Comment: Ah, weird. /15char